# Go: Type Assertions - Is there an error in the spec?

Tags: go, type-assertion

Is there an error in the [Go Spec Type Assertions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions)?

> A type assertion used in an assignment statement or initialization of the special form
>
> ```
> v, ok = x.(T)
> v, ok := x.(T)
> var v, ok = x.(T)
> var v, ok interface{} = x.(T) // dynamic types of v and ok are T and bool
> ```
>
> yields an additional untyped boolean value.

What is the last example supposed to be and mean?
`var v, ok interface{} = x.(T)` ?

I get an error in Go 1.19
`syntax error: unexpected interface, expecting := or = or comma`

Comment: "Is there an error in the spec?" If you come up with such a question: Ask yourself how likely it is that you are the first to notion that error. Then look harder for typos on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those lines are attempting the same operation: a type assertion of `x` to type `T`. The value, `ok`, determines whether or not the assertion was successful. In the last example you provided, the only difference is that instead of Go determining the type for `v` and `ok`, you've provided a type of `interface{}` for both. Declaring `v` and `ok` as `interface{}` doesn't change the values they contain. It would allow you to send them to functions or add them to collections that expect a type of `interface{}`, at which point they'd have to be asserted again.

Comment: Ah, it's a var declaration (as interface{}) as well as assignment. Thanks. It doesn't compile though - `syntax error: unexpected interface, expecting := or = or comma`

Comment: There is no “cast” or “typecast” in Go, these are type assertions, which are different from how most languages define casting.

Comment: @Zaphod, it does compile, you must have a typo somewhere. https://go.dev/play/p/sjrx1tmOEXl

Comment: @JimB Sorry, my language was imprecise. That was what I meant. I have modified the answer to use the proper words.